# Set a size to an Image on Android and keep its quality

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

I have an ImageView and I want to set a specific size for that, which I did, in my smartphone it runs ok, but in my tablet the image gets pixelate, how can I set the image size without compromise its quality?

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgViagem"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAgenda"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
                android:src="@drawable/viagens_home_hover"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding different resolution of the image 'viagens_home_hover' in each drawable folder i.e.
add
72x72 image in drawable-mdpi
92x92 image in drawable-hdpi
144X144 image in drawable-xhdpi

Comment: I`m using 144X144 image

Comment: Can you mention the tablet name on which image gets pixelate